# How do we differentiate long vowels from short vowels in English

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, vowels, vowel-length

I was finding a school for my toddler. I saw this new theory called long vowels and short vowels

The teacher talk about *apple*, which she read something like "eiple" and the *hat*, which she claims use short vowels.

She says that some vowels are long vowels and some vowels are short vowels.

Now I know where I got my accent. I never knew about it. In Indonesian language every vowel have just one spelling.

That being said, she does sound like native speakers.

The question is:

How do we know when we should use long vowels and when we should use short vowels. For example, is a in apple short or long? Is the *a* in *hat* short or long? Do we sort of just memorize that or is there a rule.

Comment: I am not aware of a dialect in which /eɪpl/ would be correct; the *a* in *apple* is short. It would be long in *ape*, though.

Comment: There is a specific Edinburgh-Morningside accent which does this (leading to an amusing joke about /seɪcks/ instead of bin bags...)

Comment: "I saw this new theory called long vowels and short vowels" -- not exactly a new theory. The teacher is right, of course. See also my comment below at Billy's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no good rule - children struggle with this when learning to write. There are a few rules of thumb that hold in most cases, though:

- Diphthongs (ou, ie, ei, eu, ...) are long (accOUnt), unless they're unstressed and turn into a schwa (succOUr)
- Single vowels (a, e, i, o, u) are short before double consonants (AttAck)
- Single vowels are long if they are followed by a single consonant and then an 'e', all in the same syllable (sAve, mOle), and in *-ing* forms of such verbs (sAve -> sAving)
- Single vowels are short if they are followed by a single consonant in the same or next syllable, unless the above applies (cAt, At-lAs, nO-mEn-clA-ture)
- And loads of exceptions to all of these rules, and they vary across dialects and idiolects. The consonants 'r', 'w' and 'y' do funny things to vowels, too.

These might help a little:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length#Short_and_long_vowels_in_English

http://improvingenglishspelling.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/long-and-short-vowels.html

Comment: Excellently set out. The main point to note is "And loads of exceptions to all of these rules, ". The teacher is right, of course. Only, she seems to be over-simplifying things, in consideration for the little ones.

Comment: Do we really need to learn this to learn english well? I mean if I say apple instead of eipple, would white guy fail to understand?

Comment: @JimThio: Huh? If you want to learn English *well*, you need to pronounce words correctly, of course! If you say 'eipple' (or 'oople' or 'ipple' or 'addle' or 'affle' or anything else incorrect), you are making it very difficult for your listener to understand what you're saying. Long 'a' and short 'a' are completely different vowels, and we do not usually think of them as being related when they're spoken. If you make three of these mistakes in the same sentence, it's unlikely that you'll be understood.

Comment: Oh really. So apple is short vowel right. I mean a followed by 2 pp.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's the same vowel as in 'hat'.

Comment: (By the way, in case you don't know: calling English speakers 'white guy' is likely to cause offence!)

Comment: The reason I asked about why I should learn the difference is because english language has tons of dialog. There is british english, there is american english, there is singlish, malay english, and who knows what. I just want to learn english, rather than fretting over which dialect. I am not a spy. Not sure why calling someone white guy is offensive. It sounds neutral to me and 100 years ago, may actually be respectful.

Comment: @JimThio: (1) Those dialects *are* English. You have to speak one and understand them all, just like all native English speakers. (2) Not all white guys speak English, and not all native English speakers are white guys. (3) Gratuitously referencing someone's skin colour is not generally acceptable in British, American, Australian etc. cultures. If you learn the language without the culture, you still won't be able to communicate. (4) Pronouncing "apple" as "eipple" is - as far as I know - wrong in *all* dialects. It's not a case of 'fretting'. If you say "eipple", nobody will understand you.

Comment: I said "white guys" because it sounds funny to me. I am sorry if I offend anyone. I thought it'll cheer people up.

Comment: @JimThio: Don't worry about it. :)

Comment: Jim Thio, pronouncing vowels also depends on which English you learn. They are not always the same, in every kind of English. What is important is to choose one kind of English and use it consistently but, also be aware of the others and how they are different from each other.

Answer (score 6):

How do you know if a vowel in English is long or short? Here are five simple decoding strategies.  Although these reading strategies apply to only one-syllable words, these strategies can be applied on the syllable-level in multi-syllabic words.

1. If there is one consonant after the vowel, the vowel will be short. (Examples: an, pet, big, hot, cup)
2. If two consonants follow the vowel, the vowel will be short. (Examples: ant, rent, mist, cost, crust)
3. If the vowel stands alone, the vowel is long. (Examples: me, hi, go)
4. If an E is at the end of the word and it is preceded by another vowel, the E at the end of the word is silent and the first vowel is long. Silent E makes the first vowel long. (Examples: name, Pete, fine, home, cute or dune)
5. If two vowels are adjacent (next to each other), the second vowel is silent, making the first vowel long. (Examples: main, dream, lied, road, fruit)

NOTE: It is important to clarify that the terms "long" vowel and "short" vowel do not indicte the length of the vowel, but rather the sound of the vowel. In linguistic contexts, the terms "long" and "short" are referred to as "tense" and "lax" vowels, respectively.

NOTE 2: Yes there are exceptions, but when you apply these rules on the syllable-level you will find that for the most part they work quite well.

Comment: I touched up the formatting. Hope you don't mind. And welcome to EL&U!

Answer (score 4):

The letters   a,  i,  o,  u   (and sometimes e too) have two common short and long sounds, as in:

flat, flatten – inflate; hid, hidden – hide; dot, dotty – dote; tub, tubby – tube; (hem, hemmed – theme).

I have explained this short / long (or closed / open) vowel spelling system in  http://improvingenglishspelling.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/long-and-short-vowels.html like this:
When a, e, i, o and u are followed by just one consonant, or several consonants and a vowel, they are 'closed' and are supposed to have a short sound, as in:

```
 am, ample, ten, tender, pin, pinked, drop, droplet, bun, bunting.
```

If a single consonant after a, e, i, o and u is followed by a vowel, they are supposed to be ‘open’ and long, as in:

```
 hale, halo; peter, period; fine, final; sole, solo; tube, tubular'.
```

If a stressed vowel before a single consonant and another vowel is to stay short, it is supposed to be followed by a doubled consonant:

```
 attitude, petty, pinnacle, dotty, bunny.
```

Hence: cut + er = cutter, prefer + ed = preferred, enter + ed = entered, cute + er = cuter.

Thousands of English words conform to this system. Unfortunately, there are also hundreds words which break the ‘closed /short' and 'open / long’ vowel spelling method in one or more of five different ways. ...
 My blog  http://englishspellingproblems.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/irregular-spellings-in-4217-common-words_7864.html shows all common words which do so.

The only English vowel spelling that has a completely regular pronunciation is ee, as in 'keep sleep deep'. All others have some exceptions - http://englishspellingproblems.blogspot.com/2009/12/reading-problems.htm.
Beyond a very basic level, pupils have to learn to read and write English words one by one.

Comment: Please sum up or quote the crucial bits right here. Link-only answers are subject to deletion without further notice, possible link rot being only one reason. Thank you.

Comment: If my above post has to be deleted, because it consists mainly of links, so be it. If I gave a reasonably comprehensible full explanation, it would take up many pages. Also, it is impossible to grasp this issue without looking at the relevant words.

Comment: Nearly all English pronunciation and spelling rules have exceptions. E.g. those listed in post 5 above

Comment: E.g. those listed in post 5 above •Diphthongs (ou, ie, ei, eu, ...) are long, but not in 'double, friend, heifer, head, foot.. 
 •Single vowels (a, e, i, o, u) are short before double consonants - except all, grass, kind, roll, only, tomb, truth.. 
 •Single vowels are long if they are followed by a single consonant and then an 'e' - except 'have, never, imagine, some....Dropping surplus -e endings would be a simple way of making the long and short vowel system more transparent (hav, giv - save, drive).

Comment: What about 'divorcee' or 'Beethoven'? (sometimes pronounced di-vor-say and Bay-toe-ven)

Comment: @Mitch, Beethoven is a surname and a German one;  divorcee, a French loan word, is more interesting and I've also heard it pronounced two different ways.

Comment: @Mari-LouA All interesting and informative but irrelevant points. An English Language learner doesn't know any of that, and so would mispronounce them using the meta-rule "'ee' has no exceptions".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, good point about the origin of these loan words. The first word would be more obvious as a loan word if it were spelled *divorcée*. That acute accent on the e makes it an "ay" sound. Mitch, I don't think that the origin is "irrelevant." The origin is critical.

Answer (score -1):

In school they said that a long vowel sound will simply be the vowel saying its name. A short vowel will be any vowel that says otherwise. However I'm not sure how this works when you use two letters to get a sound. A in hay would be a long vowel, a in hat would be a short vowel. E in he is a long vowel, e in edit would be a short vowel sound. This concept goes for all the vowels except for y which is special I think.

Comment: OP is asking how to know whether a vowel in a written text is long or short. You are defining long and short vowels, which is not what the OP asked for.